# Can adding more LEFT OUTER JOINS affect the previous columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join

In my code I need to get data about certain part numbers, I encountered a weird problem when I run my code with:

```
SELECT 
                tblensembleunepiece.ENSPIECEID,
                tblensembleunepiece.NOPIECE As 'Part Number', 
                tblensembleunepiece.DESCRIPTIONENSP As 'Description', 
                tblensembleunepiece.QTEMIN As 'Min',
                tblensembleunepiece.QTEMAX As 'Max',
                tbltypepiece.TITRETYPE, 
                case 
                                when CONSOMMABLE='true' Then 'Consumeable'
                                else 'Rotable' end As 'Utilization',
                sum(tblitem.NBPOURPACK) As 'Serviceable',
                sum(case when tblquarantaine.BER = 'false' Then 1 else 0 END ) As 'Quarantine Repairable',
                sum(case when tblquarantaine.BER = 'true' Then 1 else 0 end) As 'Quarantine BER/Scrap',
                sum(case when tblbonsortieitem.VAREVENIR = 'true' Then 1 else 0 end) As 'Repair Line',

    sum(case when (tblhistorique.REMARQUE LIKE "Added to operation cost%" OR tblhistorique.REMARQUE LIKE "Added to operational cost%")
        then (substring_index( LTRIM(substring_index(tblhistorique.REMARQUE, 'Qty:', -1)), '.', 1)+0)
        when (tblhistorique.REMARQUE LIKE "Removed from operation cost%" OR tblhistorique.REMARQUE LIKE "Removed from operational cost%") 
        then (substring_index( LTRIM(substring_index(tblhistorique.REMARQUE, 'Qty:', -1)), ' ', 1)*(-1))  else 0 end)
FROM 
                tblensembleunepiece
                JOIN tbltypepiece ON tblensembleunepiece.TYPEPIECEID = tbltypepiece.TYPEPIECEID
                JOIN tblitem ON tblensembleunepiece.ENSPIECEID = tblitem.ENSPIECEID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tblquarantaine ON tblquarantaine.ITEMID = tblitem.ITEMID 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tblbonsortieitem ON tblbonsortieitem.ITEMID = tblitem.ITEMID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tblhistorique ON tblhistorique.ITEMID = tblitem.ITEMID 
WHERE 
                tblensembleunepiece.NOPIECE<>'' 

GROUP BY tblensembleunepiece.ENSPIECEID;
```

Then I get erroneous data.  Although, before I added the last sum statement in the SELECT clause and the last LEFT OUTER JOIN in the FROM clause everything worked fine.

The Serviceable column is the one that gives errors when the extra code is added, it is outputting values that are 4 times larger than they should be (not all the values but most).

Is it possible that adding more LEFT OUTER JOINS can cause the previous columns to change?

Comment: Why would you add a join that didn't affect what was selected? It would be sort of pointless...

Comment: I cant use subqueries the database doesnt support it

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  This is just saying that there are multiple matches in the new table to the previous table.

One way to fix this is by aggregating the new table by the key used for the join, before doing the join.

In other words, the table `tblhistorique` has multiple row with the same `ITEMID`.  This multiplies the number of rows being processed by the aggregation, resulting in multiply counting some values.

EDIT:

Your aggregation only uses columns from `tblhistorique`.  You can move the logic into a subquery and do the aggregation there:

```
SELECT . . .,
       val
FROM 
                tblensembleunepiece
                JOIN tbltypepiece ON tblensembleunepiece.TYPEPIECEID = tbltypepiece.TYPEPIECEID
                JOIN tblitem ON tblensembleunepiece.ENSPIECEID = tblitem.ENSPIECEID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tblquarantaine ON tblquarantaine.ITEMID = tblitem.ITEMID 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tblbonsortieitem ON tblbonsortieitem.ITEMID = tblitem.ITEMID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN (select itemId,
                                        sum(case when (th.REMARQUE LIKE "Added to operation cost%" OR th.REMARQUE LIKE "Added to operational cost%")
        then (substring_index( LTRIM(substring_index(th.REMARQUE, 'Qty:', -1)), '.', 1)+0)
        when (th.REMARQUE LIKE "Removed from operation cost%" OR tblhistorique.REMARQUE LIKE "Removed from operational cost%") 
        then (substring_index( LTRIM(substring_index(th.REMARQUE, 'Qty:', -1)), ' ', 1)*(-1))  else 0 end) as val
                                 from tblhistorique th
                                ) th ON th.ITEMID = tblitem.ITEMID 
. . .
```

Comment: You are correct there are multiple instances of each ITEMID in tblhistorique.  Does this mean that the previous columns are also being updated for each new instance of ITEMID that the query finds in the new columns?  Why would they do it this way?

How would I aggregate the new table, what does that mean?

Comment: Is there a way to freeze the columns I already have when going to the next ones?

Comment: This may have poor performance if there are a lot of distinct ITEMIDs in tblhistorique (full table scan + JOIN w/o index). I think it will be better to move everything except the offending JOIN to the inner query and then SELECT * from it and do the last JOIN.

Comment: Only problem is I cannot use subquesries the database im using does not support it (too old).  Is this possible without subqueries?

Comment: You can delete the sum by the number of duplications. Also you can use a temporary table instead of an subquery in this case.

Comment: @user1923086 . . . What do you mean the database is too old to support subqueries?  What version of MySQL are you using?  Also, can the database support correlated subqueries in the `select` clause?  MySQL does not support subqueries for views in the `from` clause but it does support them elsewhere in the query.

Comment: The MySQL that I am using is the most up to date, it is the database I am fetching the data from that is very old and does not support much functionality, the version is 4.0.27.